# Why my ListView inside a Fragment doesn't get updated?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a ListView inside a Fragment:

```
public class EditorFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  private EditText editor = null;
  private ListView lv = null;
  private EditText et = null;
  private File root = null;
  private String[] nomi={"test1","test2"};
  private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
                                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, parent, false);

    editor = (EditText) result.findViewById(R.id.editor);
    lv = (ListView) result.findViewById(R.id.list);
    root = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nomi );
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
    return (result);
}
```

When the user clicks a button on the ActionBar the following method gets called.

Since it contains `notifyDataSetChanged()` I expect the ListView to get refreshed, but this doesn't happen...

```
private File getTarget() {
  int i = 0;
  if(et!=null)
        FILENAME=et.getText().toString();
  if(root.list().length!=0) {
        nomi= new String[(int) root.length()];
        nomi=root.list();
  };
  aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
  return (new File(root,FILENAME));
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You are changing the `nomi` reference expecting it to change the reference inside the `aa`, but it's not right. If you want to change the `aa`'s data to change, you have to change `nomi` and set it to the `aa` again.

Instead of calling `aa.notifyDataSetChanged()` on `getTarget()`, try to create a new `ArrayAdapter` and set it to the `ListView` again.

Comment: Before calling `aa.notifyDatasetChanged` you need to update the adapter with a new data set. Dont see that happening in your code.

Comment: @LisaAnne, you are misundertanding the object references. Think of the objects as C pointers (if you have seen C before) and you might understand your error easily

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! If you post an answer I will gladly accept :-)